# Как браузер дает знать серверу, что он поддерживает HTTP/2?

Tags: http, https

Когда юзер заходит на сайт, браузер ведь не знает, поддерживает ли сайт http/2. Так же как и сервер не знает про возможности браузера. Как они договариваются между собой о поддержке http/2?

Comment: https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для выбора между HTTPS и HTTP/2+TLS — по [ALPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-Layer_Protocol_Negotiation) ([RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7301)).

Поскольку HTTPS и HTTP/2 оба могут работать по TLS 1.2 и выше, было создано расширение для TLS, ALPN, с помощью которого клиент и сервер могут договориться о доступных протоколах ещё на этапе TLS-"приветствия" (handshake). Протокол HTTP/2 идентифицируется в нём токеном `h2`, это разновидность HTTP/2, работающая поверх TLS, с шифрованием.

**"Крупные браузеры" заявили, что будут поддерживать только HTTP/2 по TLS** ([1](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2015/06/15/http2_implementation_status), [2](https://http2.github.io/faq/#does-http2-require-encryption)), поэтому других способов на практике можно запросто не встретить.

---

Для HTTP/2 по "голому" TCP-соединению (поддержка которого *так себе*, см. выше) [используется обычный механизм по заголовку `Upgrade`](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#discover-http), тот же что и для Websocket, в котором:

- клиент

  - должен совершить первый полный запрос, заявив о возможности обновить протокол до `h2c` (HTTP/2 через голый TCP) заголовком `Upgrade` и приложив **ровно один** заголовок `HTTP2-Settings` с base64-закодированными настройками протокола
- сервер, готовый это сделать:

  - должен ответить `101 Switching Protocols`

    - завершив этот ответ, начать отдавать ответ на исходный запрос уже по HTTP/2, не дожидаясь подтверждения от клиента
- сервер, не готовый это сделать:

  - может проигнорировать намерения клиента

Answer (score 3):

https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#discover-http

> **3.2 Starting HTTP/2 for "http" URIs**
>
> A client that makes a request for an "http" URI without prior knowledge about support for HTTP/2 on the next hop uses the HTTP Upgrade mechanism (Section 6.7 of [RFC7230]). The client does so by making an HTTP/1.1 request that includes an Upgrade header field with the "h2c" token. Such an HTTP/1.1 request MUST include exactly one HTTP2-Settings (Section 3.2.1) header field.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: server.example.com
> Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
> Upgrade: h2c
> HTTP2-Settings: <base64url encoding of HTTP/2 SETTINGS payload>
> ```

Перевод:

> **3.2 Инициация HTTP/2 через «http» URI**
>
> Клиент, который делает запрос на «HTTP» URI без предварительного знания о поддержке HTTP/2 на следующем хопе использует механизм HTTP Upgrade (раздел 6.7 [RFC7230]). Клиент делает это путем создания запроса HTTP/1.1, который включает в себя заголовочное поле Upgrade с текстом «h2c». Такой HTTP/1.1 запрос должен включать в себя ровно одно заголовочние поле HTTP2-Settings (раздел 3.2.1).
>
> Например:
>
> ```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: server.example.com
> Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
> Upgrade: h2c
> HTTP2-Settings: <base64url encoding of HTTP/2 SETTINGS payload>
> ```